# JavaScript for...of, for...in, or other iterative methods are not working for multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, brightcove, request-promise

My goal is to get metadata regarding videos from the [Brightcove CMS API](https://docs.brightcove.com/cms-api/v1/doc/index.html#operation/GetVideoByIdOrReferenceId) by passing video IDs.

Our videos metadata is stored in four different business units (or profiles) so I must query each business unit's endpoint separately. I do not know which video ID will be found in which business unit. I can send a maximum of 10 video IDs per call. Below are the steps required to obtain video metadata by video ID.

1) Get access `token` (this step uses client credentials which I'm supplying).

2) Pass access `token` to request object (`sendRequest`) via `options` param.

3) Parse the response and put it in a global `videosArray`.

4) Repeat steps 1 through 3 for each set of 10 unique video IDs or less (represented by a multidimensional array).

5) Repeat steps 1 through 4 for each video account (business unit).

FYI: The [boilerplate code from Brightcove](https://support.brightcove.com/generate-video-sitemaps) makes use of callbacks. I've converted that code to async/await. Perhaps someone can also suggest improvements to my async/await code if it is incorrect.

I'm using **Node 8.10**, **ES6+**, and **request-promise-native** modules (among others). Any variables that appear to be implicitly declared are declared in the global scope. I simply haven't pasted them here.

bizUnit is an array of objects as such (I have a total of four different business units to iterate over):

```
businessUnits = [
     bizUnitOne: {
          account_id: 'uhdafoia98243r2',
          client_id: 'oidahf982y229hr',
          client_secret: 'iuahf9o4398oyg',
          player_url: 'afdhy984wyyfsg',
     },
     bizUnitTwo: {
          account_id: 'uhdafoia98243r2',
          client_id: 'oidahf982y229hr',
          client_secret: 'iuahf9o4398oyg',
          player_url: 'afdhy984wyyfsg',
     }
]
```

Get Access token function declaration:

```
async function getAccessToken(bizUnit) {
// base64 encode the client_id:client_secret string for basic auth
let bodyObj,
    token;
authString = new Buffer(bizUnit.client_id + ':' + bizUnit.client_secret).toString('base64');
let payLoad = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://oauth.brightcove.com/v3/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authString,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: true
};
try {
    let result = await request(payLoad);
    bodyObj = await JSON.parse(result);
    token = bodyObj.access_token;
    return token;
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(oauthError, error);
}
```

}

Send Request declaration:

```
async function sendRequest(options) {
let requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: options.url,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + options.token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: true
};
let makeRequest = async (reqOptions) => {
    try {
        let body = await request(reqOptions);
        return JSON.parse(body);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(apiError, error);
    }
};
// make the request
await makeRequest(requestOptions);
```

}

Example of the video IDs array (theoretically, this array could have hundreds or thousands of video IDs in chunks of 10 or less):

```
videoIdsGroup = [ [53245,2352,243252,2352352,234234,234324,2342342,24242,23542,234324], [43534, 34543, 3453, 3453345] ];
```

Bringing it all together and making the request:

```
function setUpVideoRequest(bizUnit) {
(async (bu) => {
    // note that access tokens live for 5 minutes
    // but you can always request one for each call to be safe

    for (let videoIdsArr of videoIdsGroup) {
        let endPoint,
        videoIdsString = videoIdsArr.join();
        endPoint = '/accounts/' + bu.account_id + '/videos/' + videoIdsString + '&sort=' + sort;
        options.url = baseURL + endPoint;
        options.token = await getAccessToken(bizUnit);
        const videos = await sendRequest(options);
        videosArray = videosArray.concat(videos);
    }
})(bizUnit);
```

}

Initiating the execution:

```
   for (let bu of businessUnits) {

        /*the counter below is to reveal how many times and in what sequence this for...of loop is executing. my console.log indicates that this loop iterates through all businessUnits immediately, but then it runs again and eventually succeeds in some of the calls and repeats those calls even though it already got data.*/ 
        let parentCounter = 0;
        console.log("BizUnit COUNTER", parentCounter++);

        try {
    promises.push(setUpVideoRequest(bu));
} catch (error) {
    throw error;
}
```

}

Error message I'm getting (this one repeats and then I sporadically get some data and then the error repeats again):

```
    statusCode: 400,
  message: '400 - {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The &quot;client_id&quot; parameter is missing, does not name a client registration that is applicable for the requested call, or is not properly authenticated."}',
```

I know that the for...of loops are not running correctly, but I've tried a regular for loop with an [i] iterator, I've also tried a for...in, and I've tried forEach. None of them work correctly.

I just want to be able to make a request per account ID (business unit) and per videos array and obtain all the video metadata and put it in the global `videosArray` by way of something like this:

```
Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    promiseVidArray.push(results);
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help and insight.

Comment: If you want to use `await`, you must have a promise and not use the `request` callback API. If you are using `request-promise-*` already, just don't pass a callback at all! Have a look at its documentation.

Comment: Also, never have an `async function` accept a `callback`. You should just `await` the async stuff you are doing, and then `return`.

Comment: If you are not familiar with `async`/`await´ yet, try using promises without any syntactic sugar, i.e. use `.then()` calls only

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. I have cleaned up the structure related to promises. Will edit the original post and add the new version. Still facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket in the businessUnits object

```
businessUnits = [{
     bizUnitOne: {
          account_id: 'uhdafoia98243r2',
          client_id: 'oidahf982y229hr',
          client_secret: 'iuahf9o4398oyg',
          player_url: 'afdhy984wyyfsg',
     },
     bizUnitTwo: {
          account_id: 'uhdafoia98243r2',
          client_id: 'oidahf982y229hr',
          client_secret: 'iuahf9o4398oyg',
          player_url: 'afdhy984wyyfsg',
     }
}]; // <-- Here it is the one you're missing
```

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately, my actual code did not have that issue. I typed that object exclusively for the purpose of this post and that's where I messed up. My production code is good.

Answer (score 0):

After making some corrections to my async/await syntax (thank you @Bergi), I discovered the root of the problem: I was sending incorrect client credentials for 3 out of 4 of the requests. The reason why is pretty interesting. I've detailed it below.

When you create an API authentication key in Brightcove Video Cloud you provide a name for the key, select the business segments to authorize under that key, and select the endpoints that you wish to expose under those business units.

I created one key per business unit and Brightcove provided me with a unique 'account_id', 'client_id', 'client_secret' for each key. I immediately copy/pasted those to a notepad file because the 'client_secret' disappears after 5 minutes and cannot be retrieved (you would have to delete the key and create a new one).

I logged back into Brightcove management panel today to confirm if my keys were correct. To my surprise, all four of the 'client_ids' were exactly the same (the client ids that I had copy/pasted were unique). In my API request, I was sending a unique 'client_id' per business unit because that is what Brightcove provided me when I created the API authentication key. Somehow, they all changed and became the exact same key for all four business units. I still don't understand why or how this happened.

Thus, my requests were failing for 3 out of the 4 accounts.